# The interior of the union of two sets expansion.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

In calculations involving sets we know that:

$\mathrm{x} \in \mathrm{E} \cup \mathrm{F} \Leftrightarrow \mathrm{x} \in \mathrm{E} \text { or } \mathrm{x} \in \mathrm{F}$

Applying the same rule on $\overline{E \cup F}$ where $\overline{E \cup F}$ denotes the closure of the union of the set $E$ and $F$, we get:

$\mathrm{x} \in\overline{E \cup F} \Leftrightarrow \mathrm{x} \in \bar{E} \cup \bar{F} \Leftrightarrow \mathrm{x} \in \bar{E} \; or \; \bar{F}$

since:
$\overline{E \cup F}=\bar{E} \cup \bar{F}$

My question is: How can we write the interior of the union of $E$ and $F$ in the same way we did for the exterior of the union of these two elements, knowing that the property for interior $E^{\circ} \cup F^{\circ} \subset(E \cup F)^{\circ}$ is an inclusion and not an equality like in the case of exterior.

i.e. $\mathrm{x} \in ({E \cup F})^{\circ} \Leftrightarrow ??$

Answer (score 2):

In general, for a subset $S\subseteq X,$ since $S^\circ=X\setminus \overline{(X\setminus S)},$ $x\in (E\cup F)^\circ=X\setminus \overline{(X\setminus (E\cup F))}=X\setminus \overline{((X\setminus E)\cap (X\setminus F))}.$

However, unlike in the case of union, for subsets $S,T\subseteq X,$ it is in general not true that $\overline{S\cap T}= \overline S\cap \overline T,$ and the only thing one can say with certainty is $\overline{S\cap T}\subseteq \overline S\cap \overline T.$

Thus, the strongest statement we can make that follows the above pattern is, since $X\setminus \overline{((X\setminus E)\cap (X\setminus F))}\supseteq X\setminus (\overline{(X\setminus E)}\cap \overline{(X\setminus F)})=(X\setminus \overline{(X\setminus E)})\cup (X\setminus\overline{(X\setminus F)})=E^\circ\cup F^\circ,$

$x\in E^\circ$ or $x\in F^\circ \Rightarrow x\in E^\circ\cup F^\circ\Rightarrow x\in (E\cup F)^\circ$

**P.S. Counterexample to $\overline{S\cap T}= \overline S\cap \overline T$:**

Let $X=\{0,1\}$ with closed sets $\emptyset, \{0\}, X.$ Then, $\overline{\{0\}}\cap\overline{\{1\}}=\{0\}\cap X=\{0\},$ but $\overline{\{0\}\cap\{1\}}=\overline \emptyset=\emptyset.$

Comment: I was asking for the equivalence of the last statement, so the converse is still needed. You proved the known property that the int of E union the int of F is included in the int of (E union F) which is trivial to obtain the expansion from there, I am asking for an expansion the other way around (i.e. an equivalence rather than an implication)

Comment: I'm saying there is no meaningful equivalence of the form you like.